# How can I get the name/file of the script from sitecustomize.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run any Python script, I would like to see the script's filename appear in the Windows command line window's titlebar. For example, if I run a script called "`mytest.py`", I want to see "`mytest`" in the titlebar. I would like this to be automatic, so I don't have to add code to every one of my scripts.

Currently I'm attempting to do this with `sitecustomize.py`, because when Python is run, including from double-clicking a Python script, `sitecustomize` is imported before the script runs.

I've tried getting `__main__`'s `__file__` and `sys.argv`, but `sitecustomize` doesn't see either:

file `sitecustomize.py`:

```
import __main__, sys
print "hasattr __main__.__file__:", hasattr(__main__, "__file__")
print "hasattr sys.argv:", hasattr(sys, "argv")
print "-" * 60
```

file `mytest.py`:

```
import sys
print "__file__ is:", __file__
print "sys.argv is:", sys.argv
raw_input() # don't end the script immediately
```

output:

```
hasattr __main__.__file__: False
hasattr sys.argv: False
------------------------------------------------------------
__file__ is: C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\mytest.py
sys.argv is: ['C:\\Documents and Settings\\Owner\\Desktop\\mytest.py']
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is?  Why can't you just use \_\_file\_\_ ?

Comment: I want to do it for every script, without adding it to every one of my python scripts manually. sitecustomize.py is imported any time Python starts up. Is something else unclear?

Comment: Your question does not make sense, hence no answers.  Please show us how you are planing on using this.

Comment: I tried rephrasing my question. I hope it's easier to understand. I'm just planning on using it for my own convenience - say if I have many scripts open, I want to identify them at a glance.

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad you asked!  I now have it working for my scripts, and it's pretty cool.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import time
from ctypes import windll

class SetTitle(object):
    def __del__(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        command = ' '.join(sys.argv)
        windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA(command)

sys.argv = SetTitle()
```

This is for Python 2.x -- for 3.x you need to change `SetConsoleTitleA` to `SetConsoleTitleW` (last letter changes from A to W).

How it works:  since the sys.argv object does yet exist, I create an object and assign it to sys.argv; then, when Python assigns the actual argv to sys.argv, my object is tossed, and the `__del__` method is called;  the `__del__` method is then able to access the real argv and set the title bar accordingly.  I put the 1 second sleep in just to avoid any possible race conditions, but I'm not sure it's necessary.  If you don't want to see all the command-line args, you can pre-process command any way you like.

My thanks to the folks on python-win32 mailing list, and Thomas Heller in particular, for helping with the 'set title' portion of this question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to make `sys.argv` a descriptor?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: descriptors only work with class attributes, and `argv` is a module attribute.  So, if it could work, it would be cleaner -- but it won't.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run any Python script, I would
>   like to see the script's filename
>   appear in the Windows command line
>   window's titlebar. For example, if I
>   run a script called "mytest.py", I
>   want to see "mytest" in the titlebar.
>   I would like this to be automatic, so
>   I don't have to add code to every one
>   of my scripts.

I think you should add this functionality to all your scripts by a module and not by hacking it into sitecustomize.py. Also even if you still want to go the sitecustomize path you will need to pass `__file__` from your script, which means you will not get around to add some code to all your scripts.

What you certainly can do is to put that code into a module and then import it in all your python scripts. Like I mentioned above, you need to pass `__file__` from your main script otherwise you will get the modules filename. Also there is no need to import `__main__` to retrieve `__file__`.