# Running Python startup code after modules are loaded

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

I'm working with Jupyter notebooks and Python kernels with a SparkContext. A coworker has written some Python code that wires Spark events with ipykernel events. When we import his module from a notebook cell, it works in all combinations we need to support: Python 2.7 and 3.5, Spark 1.6 and 2.x, Linux only.

Now we want to enable that code automatically for all Python kernels. I put the import into our `sitecustomize.py`. That works fine for Spark 2.x, but not for Spark 1.6. Kernels with Spark 1.6 don't get an `sc` anymore, and something is so screwed up that unrelated imports like `matplotlib.cbook` fail. When I delay that import for a few seconds using a timer, it works.
Apparently, the code in `sitecustomize.py` is executed too early for importing the module which connects Spark with the ipykernel.

I'm looking for a way to delay that import until Spark and/or ipykernel are fully initialized. But it should still execute as part of the kernel startup, before any notebook cells get executed.
I found [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6879344/5629418) to delay code execution until `sys.argv` is initialized. But I don't think it can work on global variables like `sc`, considering that Python globals are still local to modules. So far, the best I can come up with is using a timer to check every second whether certain modules are present in `sys.modules`. But that isn't very reliable, because I don't know how to distinguish a module that's fully initialized from one that's still in the process of being loaded.

Any ideas on how to hook in startup code that executes late during startup? A solution that is specific to pyspark and/or ipykernel would satisfy my needs.

Comment: I played around some more with checking for presence of modules... it's not good enough. I can get the import to work reliably, but the intended functionality may or may not work afterwards. The list of loaded modules at the time of the import was identical.

Comment: Have you checked `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable? From `python --help`: *`PYTHONSTARTUP`: file executed on interactive startup (no default)*

Comment: @piotr-dobrogost: It's not an interactive startup. We're calling Python with `-m ipykernel` to start the IPython kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, you don't really give many details about what errors you encounter.

I think the canonical way to customize startup behaviour for the ipython kernel is to setup a config file and set the `exec_lines` option.

For example you would put in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

```
# sample ipython_config.py
c = get_config()

c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'import numpy',
    'import scipy'
]
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files = [
    'mycode.py',
    'fancy.ipy'
]
```

Comment: I don't get an error message or log output or anything. It's just not working :-( I'll have a look at exec_lines, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I see that ipykernel also has a mechanism to load extensions. Don't know yet if this solves my problem, but it certainly answers my question.